# How do make the answerlabel to a quiz show correct when the right answer is written and incorrect when the wrong answer is written?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Then how to I allow only a next question button appear when only the right answer is written? I am using Swift! Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

This is my code and at 
    import UIKit

```
class InputViewController1: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var correctAnswerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var inputTextField: UITextField!

var enteredAnswer: String?

var correctAnswer = "Correct Answer = Small"

override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InputViewController1.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InputViewController1.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    inputTextField.delegate = self

    titlesForLabels()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func titlesForLabels() {
    questionLabel.text = "What is the size of the lesion(s)?"
    correctAnswerLabel.text = correctAnswer
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = true

    inputTextField.text = nil
    inputTextField.enabled = true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    })
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    enteredAnswer = textField.text

    checkForCorrectAnswer()

    return true
}

func checkForCorrectAnswer() {
    if enteredAnswer!.lowercaseString == correctAnswer.lowercaseString {
        print("Correct")
        correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else {
        print("Wrong Answer")
        correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = false
}
```

}

Comment: At first glance, it seems that you have set `correctAnswer` to "Correct Answer = Small", and then compared this to the answer entered in you `textField`. So unless the user enters "Correct Answer = Small" the test will always fail. Do you mean for the user to just enter "Small", "small", or "SMALL"? If so, changed `correctAnswer` to just "Small" like so: `var correctAnswer = "Small".

Comment: @Ike10 Whoops, good find thanks!

Comment: If I want to have a button (like a next button to the next question) show up only if the user gets the correct answer (i.e .Small), do you know what the code would be to implement that? I am new to Swift

Comment: You should edit you question to ask that. I will write an answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Please study this code very carefully before asking questions. Using the `addTarget` method for `UIControlEvents.EditingChanged` (`.EditingChanged`), you can alter the properties of your `InputViewController` with the live current value of your `inputTextField`. This is done in the `textDidChange` function. Notice also, that `nexButton.alpha` is set to `0.0` in `viewDidLoad` and altered accordingly in both `textDidChange` and `checkForCorrectAnswer`.

```
class InputViewController1: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var correctAnswerLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

  @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {


  }

  var enteredAnswer: String?

  var correctAnswer = "Small"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InputViewController1.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InputViewController1.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    inputTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(InputViewController1.textDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

    inputTextField.delegate = self

    nextButton.alpha = 0.0

    titlesForLabels()
  }

  func titlesForLabels() {
    questionLabel.text = "What is the size of the lesion(s)?"
    correctAnswerLabel.text = correctAnswer
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = true

    inputTextField.text = nil
    inputTextField.enabled = true
  }

  func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
      self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
  }

  func keyboardWillHide() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: {
      self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    })
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    enteredAnswer = textField.text

    checkForCorrectAnswer()

    return true
  }

  func checkForCorrectAnswer() {
    if enteredAnswer!.lowercaseString == correctAnswer.lowercaseString {
      correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.nextButton.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
      correctAnswerLabel.text = "Correct!"
    } else {
      print("Wrong Answer")
      correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
      correctAnswerLabel.text = "Incorrect!"
    }
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = false
  }

  func textDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
    enteredAnswer = inputTextField.text
    correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    correctAnswerLabel.text = "Incorrect!"
    if enteredAnswer!.lowercaseString != correctAnswer.lowercaseString {
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.nextButton.alpha = 0.0
      }, completion: nil)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey when I do what you suggested I get a red error saying that type UIView has no member animate

Comment: are you working in swift 2.3 or 3? @Babz

Comment: Also is there a way making the words correct and incorrect come up in the answer label instead of the answer? For example if the answer is Small and the user puts Medium then the answerlabel should say Incorrect! Then only when the correct answer is written (Small), will a button appear to the next question

Comment: I suggest you elaborate your request and edit your question @Babz. Once, you do that I can help you.

Comment: I am using xcode 7.3.1

Comment: @Babz please edit your original question.

Comment: Since you are using Xcode 7.3.1, use `animateWithDuration` instead of `animate`. And the button should already only show when the correct answer is given, to make the answer label say incorrect see my edits @Babz

Comment: Sorry Ike10 but how would the code look like with the animateWithDuration? Like UIViewWithDuration... Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Babz See my edits. Also, long comment threads like this should be avoided. You should always try to achieve some of your requests on your own first.

Comment: I understand but I have been trying to figure this out for hours. Also swift changed the code to:  
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.nextButton.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: nil)
However, this button currently is always there, it does not just appear when the right answer is written like I would like it to. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Babz make sure you set the `nextButton`'s `.alpha` property to 0 in `viewDidLoad` and reset the `alpha` value to 0 in the `@IBAction` for the `nextButton` (how to do this is shown in the last code section of my answer).

Comment: the issue is that if you give the wrong answers, the button is not there. However, if you give the correct answer, the button appears. Although, if you change the answer to an incorrect answer, the button is still there. I would like to remove the button when you change the correct answer to an incorrect answer - if that makes any sense

Comment: @Babz see my edits.

Comment: @Babz No problem, I love to help! If this helped you can you please accept this answer as correct by pressing the checkmark underneath the upvote/downvote buttons?